# Count of matching word, pattern or value from unix korn shell scripting is returning just 1 as count

Tags: shell, unix, count, grep

I'm trying to get the count of a matching pattern from a variable to check the count of it, but it's only returning 1 as the results, here is what I'm trying to do:

```
x="HELLO|THIS|IS|TEST"
echo $x | grep -c "|"
```

Expected result: 3

Actual Result: 1

Do you know why is returning 1 instead of 3?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`grep -c` counts lines not matches within a line.

You can use awk to get a count:

```
x="HELLO|THIS|IS|TEST"

echo "$x" | awk -F '|' '{print NF-1}'

3
```

**Alternatively you can use `tr` and `wc`:**

```
echo "$x" | tr -dc '|' | wc -c

3
```

Comment: I'm getting these syntax errors:
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1

Comment: [See this working here](http://ideone.com/oH7jzP) What is your awk version?

Comment: That one worked for me! Thank you very much @anubhava!

Comment: @JavierSalas you are using old, broken awk (/bin/awk on Solaris). Never use that awk, on Solaris use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk instead. Anubhava your logic is slightly wrong as it'll print a count of `-1` for an empty line, it should be `awk -F '|' '{print (NF ? NF-1 : NF)}'`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo "$x" | grep -o '|' | grep -c .
3
```

`grep -c` does not count the number of matches.  It counts the number of *lines* that match.  By using `grep -o`, we put the matches on separate lines.

This approach works just as well with multiple lines:

```
$ cat file
hello|this|is
a|test
$ grep -o '|' file | grep -c .
3
```

Answer (score 0):

The `grep` manual says:

> grep, egrep, fgrep - print **lines** matching a pattern

and for the `-c` flag:

> instead print a count of matching **lines** for each input file

and there is just one **line** that match

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$ x="HELLO|THIS|IS|TEST"; echo -n "$x" | sed 's/[^|]//g' | wc -c
3
```

With only one pipe with [perl](/questions/tagged/perl):

```
echo "$x" |
  perl -lne 'print scalar(() = /\|/g)'
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `grep` for this.

```
pipe_only=${x//[^|]}  # remove everything except | from the value of x
echo "${#pipe_only}"  # output the length of pipe_only
```